# C# Group the objects of list by property

Tags: c#, linq, arraylist, group-by, grouping

I'm very new to C# and bad at explaining, hope the given input and output data will help.

I have a JSON file that contains pairs of strings which are keys use to identify something. Each key can be part of multiple pairs. I read the JSON data into a list of objects (called `TopComparison`). For any particular key, I need to scan through the list and find all the matches. It can match any one of the two keys in a pair.

I started with creating an object to store one pair:

```
class TopComparison
        {
            public string first_submission { get; set; }
            public string second_submission { get; set; }
        }
```

and I have a list for all the elements in the JSON file `List<TopComparison> topComparisons = new List<TopComparison>();`

An example dataset might be:

```
[
                {
                    "first_submission ": "Tom",
                    "second_submission ": "EJ",
                },
                {
                    "first_submission ": "Ben",
                    "second_submission ": "Tom"
                },
                {
                    "first_submission ": "Manny",
                    "second_submission ": "harry"
                },
                {
                    "first_submission ": "Manz",
                    "second_submission ": "John"
                },
                {
                    "first_submission ": "Rocky",
                    "second_submission ": "Manz"
                }
            ]
```

and I would like to group the objects based on the occurrence of the ids whether it's in `first_submission` or `second_submission` means that any key that appears in `first_submission` or `second_submission` must be checked throughout the list for recurrence if they present in `first_submission` or `second_submission`, they must be added to the list.

So "Tom" is paired with "EJ" and "Ben" in the original data set and "Manz" is paired with "Rocky" and "John", but "Manny" is only paired with "Harry". There can be an unlimited number of matches for any key (not just two)! I want to generate a list of these pairings like below:

```
List<List<TopComparison>> topComparison_list = new List<List<TopComparison>>();

[
        [
            {
                "first_submission ": "Tom",
                "second_submission ": "EJ"
            },
            {
                "first_submission ": "Ben",
                "second_submission ": "Tom"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "first_submission ": "Manny",
                "second_submission ": "Harry"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "first_submission ": "Manz",
                "second_submission ": "John"
            },
            {
                "first_submission ": "Rocky",
                "second_submission ": "Manz"
            }
        ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution for you that equals your target output.   I haven't produced the shortest code possible, so it is easier to follow.  I also did not refactor out code to use function calls from other function calls.  It was a fun brain-buster, but is meant to be a learning stepping-stone on your way to a better framed use-case scenario.  I also, per your output, made the assumption to not have any repeated values (ie, the same item cannot be in two different lists, which fits your scenario)

Instead of making a console application, I love to use a testing project.  These are great because you can create many 'test' functions and then just set a break point on the first line of code of the method to run > right click method signature > select debug tests.  Then it will execute that test and you can walk through it and watch the variables (F10 Hotkey to step).  Visual Studio 2020 Community edition is available now for free, if you don't have it already.

To implement my solution: (.NET 6.0, Nullable=enabled)

1. Create a new solution > Add a NUnit Test Project > Name project "Grouping" > target .NET 6.0 (Long-term support) > Select Create  (install .NET 6.0 if you need to or try an earlier version if you like)
2. Delete the generated class file.  Create a new class file called "GroupingTests.cs"
3. Copy paste all of this code to be inside of the namespace.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Grouping
{
    public class TopComparison
    {
        public string? FirstSubmission { get; set; }
        public string? SecondSubmission { get; set; }
    }

    public class GroupingTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void GroupEqualProperties()
        {
            List<TopComparison> topComparisons = new List<TopComparison>();
            var comparisonOne = new TopComparison()
            {
                FirstSubmission = "Tom",
                SecondSubmission = "EJ"
            };
            var comparisonTwo = new TopComparison() { FirstSubmission = "Ben", SecondSubmission = "Tom" };
            var comparisonThree = new TopComparison() { FirstSubmission = "Manny", SecondSubmission = "harry" };
            var comparisonFour = new TopComparison() { FirstSubmission = "Manz", SecondSubmission = "John" };
            var comparisonFive = new TopComparison() { FirstSubmission = "Rocky", SecondSubmission = "Manz" };
            topComparisons.Add(comparisonOne);
            topComparisons.Add(comparisonTwo);
            topComparisons.Add(comparisonThree);
            topComparisons.Add(comparisonFour);
            topComparisons.Add(comparisonFive);

            var topComparisonList = new List<List<TopComparison>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < topComparisons.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                TopComparison comparison = topComparisons[i];

                bool continueOuterFor = false;
                foreach (var resultList in topComparisonList)
                {
                    foreach (var result in resultList)
                    {
                        if (comparison.Equals(result))
                        {
                            continueOuterFor = true;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    if (continueOuterFor) { continue; }
                }

                if (continueOuterFor) { continue; }

                bool foundMatch = false;

                for (int j = i + 1; j < topComparisons.Count; j++)
                {
                    TopComparison innerComparison = topComparisons[j];


                    if (comparison.FirstSubmission == innerComparison.FirstSubmission
                        || comparison.FirstSubmission == innerComparison.SecondSubmission
                        || comparison.SecondSubmission == innerComparison.FirstSubmission
                        || comparison.SecondSubmission == innerComparison.SecondSubmission)
                    {
                        foundMatch = true;
                        var topComparisonGroup = new List<TopComparison>() { comparison, innerComparison };

                        if (!topComparisonList.Contains(topComparisonGroup))
                        {
                            topComparisonList.Add(topComparisonGroup);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!foundMatch)
                {
                    topComparisonList.Add(new List<TopComparison>() { comparison });
                }
            }

            var asJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(topComparisonList, Formatting.Indented);
        }
    }
}
```

4. Hit CTRL K + D to auto format the page.
5. If any red squiggles scream at you > select one, hit "CTRL+." > usually take top suggested fix, such as it will pull in nuget packages or references for you.
6. Run debugger on the method as explained above.
7. local variable at bottom of script, "asJson", will hold your output

You can grab its value from your debugging Autos window, or Locals window, or double click it and > quick watch (for a comprehensive window view)

Let me know if you run into any follow up issues,
Happy coding!

P.S.  There are ? after the string properties of the TopComparison Class because Nullable is enabled in my solution, which is new-ish to C#.
P.S.S. I changed casing to match C# standards.  if you want your lower_snake_case just change the properties back to match.

my output from debugger is:

```json
[
  [
    {
      "FirstSubmission": "Tom",
      "SecondSubmission": "EJ"
    },
    {
      "FirstSubmission": "Ben",
      "SecondSubmission": "Tom"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "FirstSubmission": "Manny",
      "SecondSubmission": "harry"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "FirstSubmission": "Manz",
      "SecondSubmission": "John"
    },
    {
      "FirstSubmission": "Rocky",
      "SecondSubmission": "Manz"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: it worked for that input but if I add another object at the end of that list, like var comparisonSix = new TopComparison() { FirstSubmission = "Tom", SecondSubmission = "Max" }; it is not updating the final list. it must add to the [
    {
      "FirstSubmission": "Tom",
      "SecondSubmission": "EJ"
    },
    {
      "FirstSubmission": "Ben",
      "SecondSubmission": "Tom"
    },
{
      "FirstSubmission": "Tom",
      "SecondSubmission": "Max"
    }
  ]
if add the new object in the middle of the list, it is considering it as a separate object in the final list.

Comment: Hi, I will take another look at this as time permits.  In the meantime, can you please provide a list of requirements?  different use cases?  different sets of data perhaps and your expected outcome?
ie: can top submissions be in multiple sets or just one?  what if same top submission matches with more than one?  how are you really wanting to get this data put into the function?  ie, with a jsonString?  :-)